# Aligning buttons+images+text in a row (android)

Tags: android, image, button, alignment

I'm trying to align 3 buttons in a row in the center of the screen. Each button will have a background color, an image, and some text under the image. I've tried using LinearLayout but I can't put the image over the button. I've tried RelativeLayout, and I managed to get them in a row, but they are not in the center of the screen. Any advices?

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="85dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/light"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/hstart"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/start"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/start"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/start"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
```

[image: sample]

Comment: I got this. give me 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your Button view (your_btn_view.xml in the layout folder):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_tv"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is your layout view containing three buttons:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        layout="@layout/your_btn_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        layout="@layout/your_btn_view" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        layout="@layout/your_btn_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, access and fill in the appropriate `TextView` and `ImageView` in your `onCreate()` like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle sIS){
    super.onCreate(sIS);
    setContentView(R.layout.that_layout_above, this, false);

    LinearLayout btn1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    ((TextView)btn1.findViewById(R.id.btn_tv)).setText("my text");
    ...
```

Comment: You both deserve it xD. Thank you for your help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use a LinearLayout to hold a RelativeLayout for each button/image combination. "Nested" layouts is pretty common to get this type of visual effect.